# Calling a function from a Win32 .lib project with /clr from a project that is a pure Win32 project, no clr

Tags: .net, c++, winapi, interop, clr

I want to know how do I exactly call a function from ProjectA::ClassA::FuncA() that is a Win32 .lib with /clr from a ProjectB::ClassB::FuncB() that does not have clr support and is a pure Win32 project.
Both these projects are under same solution.

First, this is what I have tried:
1. Created the ProjectA with the .lib
2. Added the .lib path to ProjectB properties (in Linker:Input:Add.Dependencies)
3. I added the .h for the .lib created by ProjectA in ProjectB
4. Created the object for ProjectA::ClassA in ProjectB::ClassB and tried to call the FuncA().

I get the following error:

> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl ClassA::FuncA(void)" (?FuncA@ClassA@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl ClassB::FuncB(void)" (?FuncB@ClassB@@SAXXZ) Helper.obj

I am using third-party .lib s in ProjectB successfully. I follow the same process but it fails; the only difference being ProjectA() is with CLR support.

Am I missing something? Please enlighten me ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have to have CLR support to call into managed assemblies.

Comment: @rerun: I have support to CLR in ProjectA (.lib), which I use in ProjectB. So, ProjectA has CLR support, ProjectB does not. ProjectA is still a Win32 project, just that I have added CLR support to it.

Answer (score 1):

Native code can call managed code but that needs to be done in a source code file that's compiled with /clr.  You need a little adapter class that's native (no "ref") in ProjectB.  If these are instance methods then you'll need [gcroot<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx) in the adapter to store a reference to the managed class.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am able to call Managed functions implemented in ProjectA from ProjectB - both are Win32 projects as explained above. However, I have now hit another unusual(rather usual) situation (for me) though. I have both static and non-static functions in ProjectA::ClassA. I have a ProjectB::ClassB object using which I want to call these ClassA functions. I am ABLE to call the non-static/instance methods in ProjectA::ClassA using ClassB object.

Comment: However I am UNABLE to call the static functions either using the class names of either the ClassA:: or ClassB:: (class ClassB : public ClassA is how I am sub-classing). 

I am new to this interop betwen "Win32+CLR" and "Win32". Any pointers??? Am I blatantly missing something?

Comment: Probably, static functions are easier.  I cannot possibly guess what you are missing, you didn't even include an error message.  Update your question.

Comment: Sorry, the error was

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl ClassA::StaticFuncA(void)" (?StaticFuncA@ClassA@@SAXXZ) Helper.obj