# How to call managed c++ dll functions in lua cpp module

Tags: c#, c++, lua-5.2

**Description**:

All my functions are defined in C# dll project.Then I wrap the c# functions in a cpp library project,Now I want to write a lua module using c++ and call the wrapper function.

**Question:**

How to call the wrapper functions in lua cpp module? Please give me some suggestions, Thanks!

**Codes:**

1. **libutilscore Project(C# DLL)**

   ```
    namespace libutilscore
    {
        public static class SharpFTP
        {
            public static string ShowHello()
            {
                return "Hello From C Sharp.";
            }
        }
     }
   ```
2. **ManagedDll Project(C++ DLL)**

   - **ManagedDll.h**

     ```
     #pragma once
     #ifdef MANAGEDDLL_EXPORTS
     #define MANAGEDDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
     #else
     #define MANAGEDDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
     #endif

     MANAGEDDLL_API const char *CPP_ShowHello();
     ```
   - ***ManagedDll.cpp***

     ```
     #include "ManagedDll.h"
     #include <string>
     using namespace System;
     using namespace std;
     using namespace libutilscore;

     namespace ManagedDll
     {
        public ref class CS_FTP
        {
            public:
               static string CS_ShowHello()
               {
                   String ^ message = libutilscore::SharpFTP::ShowHello();
                   string result = "";
                   MarshallString(message, result);
                   return result;
               }
            private:
               static void MarshallString(String ^csstr, string &stdstr)
               {
                   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
                   const char *chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(csstr)).ToPointer();
                   stdstr = chars;
                   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void *)chars));
               }

               static void MarshallWstring(String ^csstr, string &wstr)
               {
                   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
                   const char *wchars = (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(csstr)).ToPointer();
                   wstr = wchars;
                   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void *)wchars));
               }
         };
     }

     MANAGEDDLL_API string CPP_ShowHello() 
     {
         return ManagedDll::CS_FTP::CS_ShowHello();
     }
     ```

     3. **libutils Project(Lua CPP Module)**
   - libutils.h

     ```
     #pragma once

     #ifdef LIBUTILS_EXPORTS
         #define LIBUTILS_API __declspec(dllexport)
     #else
         #define LIBUTILD_API __declspec(dllimport)
     #endif // LIBUTILS_EXPORTS
     ```
   - libutils.cpp

     ```
     #include "libutils.h"
     #include "lua.hpp"

     LIBUTILS_API int showHello(lua_State *luaEnv)
     {
         const char *msg = "";
         // TODO Call DLL function
         // msg = CPP_ShowHello().c_str();
         lua_pushstring(luaEnv, msg);
         return 1;
     }

     static const luaL_Reg libutils_funcs[] = {
         {"showHello", showHello},
         {"NULL", NULL}
     };

     LIBUTILS_API int luaopen_libutils(lua_State *luaEnv)
     {
         luaL_newlib(luaEnv, libutils_funcs);
         return 1;
     }
     ```

Answer (score 1):

One option MAY be to make your "Lua CPP Module" a mixed-mode DLL.  I have answered previously on this topic, so read my instructions there on how to do it: [VC++ Calling a function of /clr project from a function of non /clr project within a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289805/vc-calling-a-function-of-clr-project-from-a-function-of-non-clr-project-with/18342009#18342009)  The short answer is that you can compile specific parts of a DLL to use the CLR without making the whole thing that way, and then call between them.

Basically, once you've figured out how to call a mixed-mode DLL from PURE C++ code, then this problem is very similar.  I don't know about restrictions on LUA C++ modules, though I would presume if they can load/call other DLLs, then you're fine.

For extra fun, then figure out how to pass information all the way back and forth.  And calling pure C++ from C#/.NET.  Or callbacks to/from each.  That gets *really* fun quickly.